# Clarifying OpenAPI callback spec

Tags: callback, openapi

I'm reading the OpenAPI callback spec, my main sources are

- https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#callback-object (spec)
- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/examples/v3.0/callback-example.yaml (example)

The **spec** (first link) states that the structure should be like:

- Operation Object

  - `callbacks`: Callback Object

    - `[pattern]`: Path Item Object

      - `get`: Operation Object
      - `post`: Operation Object
      - etc...

However the **example** (second link) describes a callback-enabled operation like so (ignored the irrelevant parts):

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /streams:
    # Code above is irrelevant, just want to keep the structure
    post: # Operation Object level
      callbacks:  # Callbacks Object
        onData: # Not sure what this is???
          '{$request.query.callbackUrl}/data': # Path Item Object level
            post: # Operation Object level
              ...
```

**My question is** where does eiter `onData` or this: `'{$request.query.callbackUrl}/data'` come from? According to the spec the **Path Item Object** should be one level above, and the `onData` (or the interpolated URL) field has no business being there, one level of nesting should be removed.

According to my interpretation, the example should either look like this if we are following the spec:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /streams:
    post: # Operation Object level
      callbacks:  # Callbacks Object
        '{$request.query.callbackUrl}/data': # Path Item Object level
          post: # Operation Object level
              ...
```

Or the spec should be like this if we are following the example:

- Operation Object

  - `callbacks`: Callback Object

    - `[name]`: Paths Item Object

      - `[pattern]`: Path Item Object

        - `get`: Operation Object
        - `post`: Operation Object
        - etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operation-level [`callbacks`](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#operationCallbacks) field is a map where the keys are arbitrary IDs/names and the values are [Callback Objects](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#callback-object). `onData` in this example is a key/name/ID of the callback.

Each Callback Object is also a map where the keys are [runtime expressions](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#key-expression) that evaluate to the request URL for the callback, and the values are Path Item Objects that define the callback request format (HTTP method, request body, expected status codes, etc.)

```yaml
paths:
  /streams:
    post:
      ...
      callbacks:

        # Arbitrary name/ID of this callback
        onData:

          # Callback Object starts here

          # This expression defines the URL to send the callback to
          '{$request.query.callbackUrl}/data':

            # Path Item Object starts here

            post:
              ...
```

Here, `{$request.query.callbackUrl}/data` means that the callback URL is constructed from the `callbackUrl` query parameter of the parent request, with `/data` appended to it. For example, if a developer sends a callback subscription request as

```
POST /streams?callbackUrl=https://myserver.com/webhooks
```

the callback will be sent to:

```
https://myserver.com/webhooks/data
```

Check out the [Callbacks](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/callbacks/) guide on swagger.io for additional explanations.

Comment: Hey Helen I missed the Map[String, CallbackObject] on callbacks :'( Thought it directly linked to CallbackObject, thank you!